# ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXYZ/myapp.jar: no such file or directory

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker

I put the `Dockerfile` into the project root.

meaning there's a `./target` directory and therein, maven generates a `spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` file.

I now want to add that to a docker image:

```
FROM centos

RUN yum install -y java    # `-y` defaults questions to 'yes'

VOLUME /tmp                # where Spring Boot will store temporary files

WORKDIR /                  # self-explanatory

ADD /target/spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar # add fat jar as "myapp.jar"

RUN sh -c 'touch ./myapp.jar' # updates dates on the application (important for caching)

EXPOSE 8080                # provide a hook into the webapp

# run the application; the `urandom` gets tomcat to start faster
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

This `ADD` fails:

```
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder119635304/myapp.jar: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution seems to be moving the comments to their own lines as they will break the commands if they're in the same line as them.

This `Dockerfile` works prefectly fine:

```
# a linux runtime environment
FROM centos

# install java; `-y` defaults questions to 'yes'
RUN yum install -y java

# where Spring Boot will store temporary files
VOLUME /tmp

# self-explanatory
WORKDIR /

# add fat jar as "myapp.jar"
ADD /target/spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar

# updates dates on the application (important for caching)
RUN sh -c 'touch ./myapp.jar'

# provide a hook into the webapp
EXPOSE 8080

# run the application; the `urandom` gets tomcat to start faster
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

Comment: yup, it's in the official docs as well: `Docker treats lines that begin with # as a comment, unless the line is a valid parser directive. A # marker anywhere else in a line is treated as an argument.` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)